# Ampersands confusion in html

Tags: html

I'm editing an HTML page but one line of code doesn't display the ampersand symbol. Here's the code:

```
return x.size()? &amp;x[0] : nullptr;          //</span> <span class="EmpItalic">pointer to first element or nullptr</span>
```

The result is always showing without the ampersand symbol.

```
return x.size()? x[0] : nullptr;          // pointer to first element or nullptr
```

This is extremely frustrating because other ampersand symbols do appear in other texts. What should I do?

Edit:

I experimented and I figured it out: It worked when I do this:

```
return x.size()? &&amp;x[0] : nullptr;          //</span> <span class="EmpItalic">pointer
```

Obviously I did && instead of the usually correct & Now the question is what exactly is && doing? Why did that work?

Comment: The code you have posted is not HTML. Is this about programming something (what?) in some programming language (what?), or what?

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela
 this is a programming book in an html form.

Comment: So the page is an HTML document displaying code in some programming language, right? The string `&amp;` is the correct way of representing “&” in character data in HTML, so if it does not work, there is *something else* in the document that causes this, or the document does not *actually* contain `&amp;`.

Comment: are you using an unusual character-encoding on your webpage?

Comment: the ampersands is displaying properly when i try your code snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/1ctrdrxm/

Comment: @Woodrow Barlow actually I don't know about the character encoding. It's a .epub file that I downloaded. I access and edit the html files inside it. Perhaps they used an unusual encoding but the normal symbol does work in other parts of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var x=x.size()? "&amp;"+x[0] : nullptr;
$(x).appendTo('.EmpItalic');
```

See also
[LINK](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/htmlchars.html)

Comment: this would result in quotation marks around the ampersands.